# Why ADF test indicates non stationarity but auto_arima selects I argument as 0?

Tags: python, arima, augmented-dickey-fuller

I have a timeseries dataset with 1 min frequency and have modeled it with ARIMA for forecasting purpose. Before modeling, I ran Augmented Dickey Fuller test and the result is:

```
ADF Statistics: -2.7713552565318396
p-value: 0.062483393638432944
Critical Values:
1% :  -3.464161278384219
5% :  -2.876401960790147
10% :  -2.5746921001665974
```

If I understood correctly, with this result I cannot reject the null hypothesis because p-value > 0.05. So the data is non stationary. To find the ARIMA order, I applied `auto_arima()` from python `pmdarima` module to the data and got `ARIMA(3,0,1)` as the best model. So the `d` argument is 0 which means there is no need to differentiate the data to make the data stationary. Is my assumption correct? Is this model reliable for forecasting?

Anyway for forecasting, I ran walk forward validation and trained the model for each new data from test dataset and got a pretty good result:
[image]

Thanks for any input.

Edit:
The whole dataset diagram:
[image]

Comment: These raw data are unsuitable for ARIMA analysis because they are so obviously nonstationary.  This has the look of the response of a system to a perturbation.  If you have a scientific model of it, consider fitting that model--the *residuals* might be amenable to time series analysis.

Comment: I don't understand this part: "If you have a scientific model of it ...". Could you elaborate on that? I will edit the question and add the entire dataset diagram. Which model is suitable for forecasting a non stationary data? What I understood from ARIMA is that the d argument would make the data stationary with differencing.

Comment: Differencing doesn't make data stationary, it removes unit roots. If the reason your data isn't stationary isn't a unit root, it does not help. You don't have a unit root, that's clear from the plots.